# Which target do I build for App Store submission including Watch extension?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, watchos

I have a universal iOS app which runs on all iOS 9 capable iPhone and iPads. The app also has a Watch extension. When I come to submit the first version to the App Store, which target do I build, archive and submit? Do I have to archive the Watch extension target, or will the Watch extension be included if I build, archive and submit the iOS app target? Or does it not matter?

Comment: The iOS app target. Extension and watch app would be bundled within the original package, automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/ConfiguringYourXcodeProject.html) states the following:

> Adding a Watch app target to your Xcode project creates two new
>   executables and updates your project’s build dependencies.

Furthermore, regarding building of the app:

> Building your iOS app **builds all three executables** (the iOS app,
>   Watch app, and WatchKit extension) and packages them together inside
>   the iOS app’s bundle.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

The iOS app target. Extension and watch app would be bundled within the original package, automatically.